# Weight in LineraLayout with RelativeLayout child does not work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I try to apply weight on an android `LinearLayout` consists of 3 elements to a `TextView` in order to occupy the most available space. The orientation of the layout is vertical and I apply the `weight="1"` on the `TextView` and no weight on the other two elements in order to force them be placed at the bottom of the screen. However it does not work, as the "large" `TextView` occupies no space at all and the second element of the `LinearLayout`, which is a `Relativelayout` occupies the whole space. Here is the layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:maxLines="100000000" >

        </TextView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/answer_panel" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/my_color"/>   

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/answer_lbl">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_answer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:lines="6"
                android:maxLines="100000000">
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/my_color"/>   

        </LinearLayout>


         <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center">

         <Button android:id="@+id/my_button"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/my_button"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/background_color"
                android:text="@string/txt_my_button"/>


     </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried also to embeed the txt_message `TextView` in a `Linearlayout` but it does not change anything. How can I put the elements in the `Relativelayout` at the bottom of the screen and let the first `TextView` occupy the remaining space?

Comment: I only see two elements in the root LinearLayout, a TextView and a RelativeLayout, is that correct?

Comment: I can see some anomalies in this layout. **1** - `fill_parent` has been deprecated since API Level 8 (some years ago) and replaced by `match_parent`. **2** - I tink you don't have clear how weights work: there must be more that only one weighted View in a LinearLayout, or it's completely ineffective. And weightSum is completely **optional**.

Comment: If LinearLayout height is match_parent and weightsum=1, your first item with weight=1 should occupy all the height of the linearlayout, i.e. all the height of the layout.

Comment: I cannot make the enclosing Layout fill_parent or match parent since what you see is only a part of the screen. Ok, false, there are two element. The button is inside the Relativelayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make you top Linear layout height android:layout_height="fill_parent" or ("match_parent")
now it is wrap content.. and remove the relative layout - it is not doing any job for you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:maxLines="100000000" >
    </TextView>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/answer_panel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ff0000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="sddsds" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_answer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:lines="6"
                android:maxLines="100000000" >
            </TextView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ff0000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/my_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="dfgfdgfdg"
                android:textColor="#ff00ff"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: color definitions are replaced with hardcodings... turn it back to the one used by you

Comment: I have adjusted my layout View according to your suggestions. After removing the Relativelayout the problem was gone. I have noticed this aberrant behavour on one more Layout, although have not not find any instruction not to use Relativelayout as child when using weights.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the textview to have more weight than the other elements inside the linearlayout, give the textview a weight of 5, for example, and the rest of the items a weight of 1. Play with weights...

Other option could be putting out of the LinearLayout, the RelativeLayout with a fixed height... If your parent Viewgroup is RelativeLayout, place the RelativeLayout with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" attribute. If it is a LinearLayout, you should go with the first option.

After reading your comment you could use:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:maxLines="100000000"
        android:above="@+id/relativeLayoutContainer" >

    </TextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/answer_panel" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/my_color"/>   

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/answer_lbl">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_answer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:lines="6"
            android:maxLines="100000000">
    </TextView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/my_color"/>   

    </LinearLayout>


     <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center">

     <Button android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/my_button"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/background_color"
            android:text="@string/txt_my_button"/>


 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I want it to have the most available. The second element has a fixed size and the first shoul occupy the rest.